# For any non-measurable set, what is the smallest measurable set which contains that non-measurable set?

Tags: measure-theory

> If we are given any non-measurable set, what is the smallest possible
> measurable set which contains that set?

We can construct such a set by taking every measurable set which contains our non-measurable set and intersecting them, but are there other constructions? What can we say about the difference between a non-measurable set and the smallest measurable set containing it?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but one thing to note is that the intersection of all measurable sets that contain a non-measurable set $B$ need not be measurable, since this might be an uncountable intersection.
Instead, you may take a sequence of sets containing $B$ with measures that converge to $c=\inf \{\mu(A):A \text{ measurable}, B\subset A\}$. The intersection of all these sets has measure equal to $c$ and contains $B$. It is not exactly the smallest measurable set that contains $B$, but it is the smallest up to a set of measure zero.